# How to get the dynamic data of fragment to another page using thymelleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to get the information(which is dynamically generated) from one html page into another html page.

I used a tag th:fragment in first html page and th:replace in second html page.

But i am getting only static content of first page, is it possible to get the dynamic data or not? can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my Java code :

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView usingToList(Model model) {
        List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add("green");
        colors.add("yellow");
        colors.add("red");
        colors.add("blue");
        model.addAttribute("message", "harika");
        model.addAttribute("colors", colors);
        
        List<String> colors2 = new ArrayList<>();
        colors2.add("pinkish");
        colors2.add("green");
        colors2.add("yellow");
        colors2.add("red");
        colors2.add("blue");
        model.addAttribute("coloring", colors2);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();   
        mv.setViewName("welcome");
        return mv;
        
    }
    
    
    
    @GetMapping("/toList")
    public String usingToList2(Model model,String color) {
        System.out.println("inside uselist");
        List<String> colors2 = new ArrayList<>();
        if(color.equals("pinkish"))
        {
            colors2.add("pinkish");
            colors2.add("amity");
            colors2.add("pimity");
        }
        if(color.equals("green"))
        {
            colors2.add("greenish");
            colors2.add("amity");
            colors2.add("Pretty");
        }
        
         model.addAttribute("colors", colors2);
        
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Below is my sample POC :

here is my fragment: `nav.html` which it load the colors dynamically. I am using this side bar fragment in all the pages. When I go another page, data in the side bar is disappering.

```
<div th:fragment="sidebar2">
    <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
        <ul class="nav flex-column" id="accordionSidebar">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a type="button"
                   id="collapse"
                   data-toggle="collapse"
                   data-target="#collapseExample"
                   aria-expanded="false" aria-
                   controls="collapseExample">
                    <span class="menu-title">Colors List</span>
                    <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu"
                        id="collapseExample2">
                        <li th:each="color : 
                               ${coloring}">
                            <a th:href="@{/toList(color=${color})}"
                               th:text="${color}"> ></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

    </div>
```

`welcome.html`:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/nav :: sidebar2"></div>
<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Spring Boot Web Thymeleaf Example</h1>
        <h2>
            <span th:text="'Hello, ' + ${message}"></span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <ol>
        <li th:each="color2 : ${colors}" th:text="${color2}"></li>
    </ol>
</main>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear with only this information. Try to add as much relevant information and code as possible. Mention what you have tried and what did not work about it.

Comment: @Wim Deblauwe, I have updated my question

Comment: Can you also add your Java controller(s) code?

Comment: Uploaded the java code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you navigate from one page to another, the `Model` is empty again (unless you are doing a `<form>` POST).

When you show the `welcome.html` Thymeleaf template via `usingToList2()`, then there is nothing in the `Model` for the `coloring` key.

To solve it, also add the `coloring` key in the `usingToList2()` controller method.

UPDATE: If all controllers need it, you can use `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {


  @ModelAttribute("coloring")
  public List<String> coloring() {
        List<String> colors2 = new ArrayList<>();
        colors2.add("pinkish");
        colors2.add("green");
        colors2.add("yellow");
        colors2.add("red");
        colors2.add("blue");
  }

}
```

Or if all methods in a single controller need it, you can just add that method in the controller class itself.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Is it something like in whichever template I am using the fragment do I need to add the coloring key in all the corresponding controller methods?

Comment: For example I am using this sidebar fragment in 3 differnt templates, I need to pass the coloring key in all the controller methods associacted for  this template

Comment: If _all_ controllers need it, you can use `@ControllerAdvice`. I'll update the answer with an example.